# Query for matching multiple rows?

Tags: sql, postgresql

We have next tables in our system

Table **object**

```
object_id    object_description
    1             "Car"
    2             "Person"
```

Table **attribute**

```
attribute_id    attribute_name
     1             "hair_color"
     2             "height"
     3             "number_of_doors"
     4             "engine_size"
```

Table **attribute_value**

```
attribute_id    attribute_value_id    value
    1                1                "black"
    1                2                "blonde"
    2                1                "more than 1 meter"
    2                2                "less than 1 meter"
    3                1                "5 doors"
    3                2                "3 doors"
    4                1                "more than 1.9"
    4                2                "less than 1.9"
```

Table **object_attribute**

```
object_id    attribute_id    attribute_value_id
    1            3                1 -- Car, number of doors,5
    1            3                2 -- Car, number of doors,2
    1            4                1 -- Car, engine size, greater than 1.9
    1            4                2 -- Car, engine size, less than 1.9
```

With this structure we are having a lot of problems getting objects that match multiple criterias (i.e. get all cars with 3 doors and engine size bigger than 1.9)
Currently we are using INTERSECTS for doing this

```
SELECT OBJECT_ID
  FROM object_attribute
 WHERE  attribute_id       = 3
   AND attribute_value     = 2 
INTERSECT 
SELECT OBJECT_ID
  FROM object_attribute
 WHERE  attribute_id       = 4
   AND attribute_value     = 1
```

There are diferent objects with diferent number of attributes, so we can't use a fixed number of JOINs or INTERSECTs anymore

Is there any way of generate multiple combinations of all attributes in a "dynamic way"?

What we would like to achieve is a dynamic query that builds a view like this:

> object_id | att_name_1 | att_value_1 | att_name_2 | att_value2 | att_name_n | attr_value_n

As the number of attributes is variable we should trigered and update of the query when a new object is inserted

Guys I think what I have in mind is not possible, so we will probably go with this dynamic query construction at runtime. Thank you all for your answers

Comment: Could you cross join object onto attribute and left join on your results?  Or if you only want attributes which exist you could start from Object_Attribute and join on both other columns?

Comment: Wich RDBM's? Retag for better visibility

Comment: You need to build a Query Dynamically, with right amount of JOINs on them.

Comment: We are using Postrgres 9.1

Comment: Long term, consider revisiting your schema altogether...

Comment: @borik your solution will definitely work but I would like to rely the hard work to the DBMS (creating a view) and just make simple querys from application code.  I'll edit my answer to clarify this

Comment: In these scenarios, you usually also have the object_id in table attribute_value. I dont think I ever saw something like the table object_atribute in such systems. Do you have the option to add that field or is the schema set?

Comment: Upvote for Denis -- you've discover that an entity-attribute-value schema, while it offers great flexibility in storing data -- is horrible at extracting data. If you're going to go in that direction then hstore may be a better implementation: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/hstore.html

Comment: @Denis the objects are extracted from an XML. In our application, somebody uses a third party tool to create polygons in a picture to identify objects (a house, a car) and assign previously defined attributes (object_height, object_direction, engine_size) that could be filled or not. The attributes values are previously defined as well. We want to report about those objects. What we don't want is to "hardcode" those attributes as they are obtained from a remote resource and they will most likely be changed in future. Could you provide some alternative schema for this behaviour?

Comment: @Aitor: if it comes from xml and you don't want to normalize it, why not store it as xml directly? I haven't looked into the PG's xml type in a while, but I'd be surprised if you cannot query rows using xpath expressions nowadays.

Comment: @Denis: The xml file is caothic, is not possible to use for storage (it's a third party software, nothing we can do here). In other hand, I don't understand why do you say the DB is not normalized? I was reviewing the tables and they all are in 3FN (I think), could you help me identifying what is breaking the normalization?

Comment: By normalized, I meant e.g. creating a table for cars with the appropriate fields. Your schema looks like you split the XML and store the attribute and values in separate tables. Methinks pure XML might somehow be easier to query if you stick to that approach -- with xpath: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-xml.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after some tests i came up with the following query:

```
select distinct 
a.attribute_name, o.object_description, av.value,
oa.attribute_id, oa.object_id, oa.attribute_value_id
from object_attribute oa
inner join attribute a on (oa.attribute_id = a.attribute_id and a.attribute_id = 3)
inner join object o on (oa.object_id = o.object_id and o.object_id = 1)
inner join attribute_value av on (oa.attribute_value_id = av.attribute_value_id and av.attribute_value_id = 2)
where 
(av.attribute_id = 3 and o.object_id = 1 and av.attribute_value_id = 2)

union
select distinct 
a.attribute_name, o.object_description, av.value,
oa.attribute_id, oa.object_id, oa.attribute_value_id
from object_attribute oa
inner join attribute a on (oa.attribute_id = a.attribute_id and a.attribute_id = 4)
inner join object o on (oa.object_id = o.object_id and o.object_id = 1)
inner join attribute_value av on (oa.attribute_value_id = av.attribute_value_id and     av.attribute_value_id = 1)
where 
(av.attribute_id = 4 and o.object_id = 1 and av.attribute_value_id = 1)
```

which results in the following:
[image: query results]

If you are using MS SQL Server I would put it in a stored procedure that accepts the three Id's as parameters.

Comment: your query is good but it does not provide a way to get those fields dynamically. I mean, you are making a joind with known values but I would like to build that query using some kind of permutation or combination dynamically.

Comment: well if you are using MS SQL Server you could build the query dynamically and use sp_executesql to run it.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx